# Ornamental hyphenation character with Xe(La)TeX

Tags: xetex, fontspec, hyphenation

Using Xe(La)TeX, how could the hyphenation character be set to any particular glyph in a given font? I'd also like to have the possibility to set a color for the glyph when used for that task and to set the glyph's size, too.

I am thinking of using some ornamental glyph as hyphenation character, but haven't figured out how to put to good use the facilities of the package `fontspec` to this end. I've tried with the key `HyphenChar`, but I wasn't able to set a value in terms of `XeTeXglyph` when I found a glyph not corresponding to any UniCode number; besides, I had no chance to set either color or size.

Comment: You can't express the character by the font specific slot where the character happens to live (which is the purpose of `\XeTeXglyph`, but only by itself or by Unicode code point.

Answer (score 3):

The character used for marking hyphenation must be chosen by its Unicode point, not with `\XeTeXglyph`.

So, if you're able to find the code point of the glyph, suppose it is U+1234, you can say

```
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,HyphenChar="1234]{MyFont}
```

However you will not be able to change its color or size, even with the `\XeTeXinterchartoks` feature, because this is executed at an earlier stage than hyphenation.