# LuaTeX equivalent of \XeTeXglyph

Tags: xetex, symbols, luatex

Does LuaTeX have an equivalent of `\XeTeXglyph`? Or better yet, is there a command to select a glyph by number that works both with `xelatex` and `lualatex`? I did find a [handmade version in German](http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/350/xetexglyph-in-lualatex), but isn’t there a better way?

I am aware of the `\symbol` command, but as far as I can tell it takes a unicode code point, and the font that I am using has several different glyphs that map to the same code point, so I need to select the glyph by glyph ID.

Comment: see [Access a glyph on fontspec using a GID (Glyph ID)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211575/7674)

Comment: Ah, right! So it appears that embedding Lua is unavoidable …