# LuaTeX: how to "steal" one glyph of other fonts and add it to the main fonts? "§" is missing!

Tags: fonts, fontspec

You may have [seen](http://www.hmb.ch/en/erasmus_mmxvi.html) that the historical museum of Basel in remembrence of the first print of a bible edited by Erasmus of Rotterdam in the year 1516 published a font called «Erasmus MMXVI». You can download the fonts [here](http://www.hmb.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/Inhalte/ZIP/Erasmus_MMXVI_Schrift.zip).

It's a beautiful fonts and using LuaTeX you can easily access its features, see here:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia, microtype}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, RawFeature=+pnum]{ErasmusMMXVI}
\newfontfamily{\ErasmSupNum}[VerticalPosition=Superior]{ErasmusMMXVI}



\deffootnotemark{\ErasmSupNum\thefootnotemark}
\newfontfamily{\ErasmUpper}[LetterSpace=6.0]{ErasmusMMXVI}

\addtokomafont{title}{\ErasmUpper}

\title{ERASMUS MMXVI}
\subtitle{OPEN-TYPE FEATURES}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle{}

Ligaturen: fi fl ff fleißig 


Hochzahlen für Fußnoten\footnote{Ha!}

Superior: \textsuperscript{1234567890}

Proportional: 0123456789

\fontspec[RawFeature=+tnum]{ErasmusMMXVI}
Monospaced: 0123456789


\itshape


Ligaturen: fi fl ff ffi ffl fh tr


fleissig\\
{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+swsh}
fleissig (Style=Swash)}

Hochzahlen für Fußnoten\footnote{Ha!}

Superior: \textsuperscript{1234567890}

\fontspec[RawFeature=+pnum]{ErasmusMMXVI}
Proportional: 0123456789



\end{document}

% Local Variables:
% TeX-engine: luatex
% End:
```

See this screenshot:
[image]

Unfortunately, the section sign "§" is missing, which I *need*. Provided, I use LuaTeX to compile, is there any possibilty to use the "§" from another font, let's say Linux Biolinum?

I found this question here: [Substitute one glyph for an alternate glyph of another stylistic set](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262795/4736) But the trouble there is to substitute the glyph from another style of the same fonts. Here in Erasmus MMXVI there is no § at all...

Comment: Just in case you actually want the _paragraph sign_ (as you write), it is called a [pilcrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilcrow) and is written "¶", not "§". The latter is the _section sign_.

Comment: @wchargin Thank you, you are right! In German language there is no pilcrow and the section sign is called "Paragraph". And the "§" ist used in juridical / legal context.

Comment: @wchargin  The meanings of the symbols are inverted "in some European usage" according to [Unicode](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf).

Comment: I had [almost the same question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417438/filling-an-empty-slot-in-a-font-with-another-glyph-from-the-same-font). The Lua code in the answer might be modified to grab a glyph from a separate font.

Comment: @svenper: How interesting! Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For example

```
\newfontfamily\LB{Linux Biolinum O}
\catcode`\§=\active
\def§{{\LB\string§}}
```

Comment: You are _fast_ !

Comment: But this only works for "§" in the text, but not, if used in a package I load (here: scrjura.sty). I admit, I did not ask that, though.

Answer (score 14):

Easy enough with `newunicodechar`:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia, microtype}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, RawFeature=+pnum]{ErasmusMMXVI}
\newfontfamily{\ErasmSupNum}[VerticalPosition=Superior]{ErasmusMMXVI}


\deffootnotemark{\ErasmSupNum\thefootnotemark}
\newfontfamily{\ErasmUpper}[LetterSpace=6.0]{ErasmusMMXVI}
\newfontfamily{\Biolinum}{Linux Biolinum O}

\addtokomafont{title}{\ErasmUpper}

\newunicodechar{§}{{\Biolinum §}}

\title{ERASMUS MMXVI}
\subtitle{OPEN-TYPE FEATURES}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle{}

Paragraphenzeichen: § \textit{§}

Ligaturen: fi fl ff fleißig 

Hochzahlen für Fußnoten\footnote{Ha!}

Superior: \textsuperscript{1234567890}

Proportional: 0123456789

\fontspec[RawFeature=+tnum]{ErasmusMMXVI}
Monospaced: 0123456789


\itshape


Ligaturen: fi fl ff ffi ffl fh tr


fleissig\\
{\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+swsh}
fleissig (Style=Swash)}

Hochzahlen für Fußnoten\footnote{Ha!}

Superior: \textsuperscript{1234567890}

\fontspec[RawFeature=+pnum]{ErasmusMMXVI}
Proportional: 0123456789

\end{document}
```

[image]

What's the difference between this and the direct `\def` as an active character? Well, the `\def` is `\protected`, so no special care is needed in moving arguments, and no trickery with `\string` is needed.

A possibly better definition, that performs the substitution only if the glyph does not exist in the current font:

```
\newunicodechar{§}{\iffontchar\font`§ §\else{\Biolinum §}\fi}
```

In order to cope with `scrjura.sty`, just add, after the `\newunicodechar` declaration,

```
\renewcommand*{\Clauseformat}[1]{§~#1}
```

This macro is the only place in `scrjura.sty` where `\S` is used.

Comment: Sorry, I only realised now, that I need a solution for a package I'm loading (scrjura.sty), which writes sections as "§ 1 Content". My question pointed in the wrong way (mea culpa!).

Comment: @KeksDose I added the workaround.

Comment: Yes, and the workaround works for your and Herberts solution as well. Thank you!