# Filling an empty slot in a font with another glyph from the same font

Tags: symbols, luatex, opentype, luaotfload

I am trying to use an existing glyph from an OpenType font to fill an empty slot in the same font using LuaLaTeX. [fontspec.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf) (v2.6g, part VI) shows a hack that can substitute *already existing* glyphs using `fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature`, but not empty slots, presumably because their name does not exist.

The font in question is the proprietary Garamond Premier Pro, but the same issue is found with EB Garamond, available in <s>outdated</s> upstream form in TeXLive as `ebgaramond` or <s>newer</s> as a Google Fonts fork from [their repo](https://github.com/octaviopardo/EBGaramond12/tree/master/fonts/otf). So while the immediate solution is to contribute to EB Garamond, the real world problem is with a font that can not be modified.

`U+03F5` (`ϵ`) (c-shaped) is normally the glyph named `epsilon1`, which is the slot I want to fill with the similar enough (in Noto Sans they are linked directly) ukrainian ie `U+0454` (`є`) which is cryptically named `afii10101` (not even [opentype.js.org](https://opentype.js.org/glyph-inspector.html) gets it right, `uni0454` will not show up in the MWE).

For text, we can use `newunicodechar` and it is working nicely, except the minor issue that copy-paste gives an ukrainian letter.

For math, neither `0x03F5`, `"uni03F5"` or `"epsilon1"` has any effect in the Lua code. We can replace the `U+03B5` if we like, but we don't. [luaotfload.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/luatex/generic/luaotfload/luaotfload.pdf) (v2.8, chapter 5) has some info on how to combine separate fonts, but not how to (re)map glyphs from scratch within a single font.

Do we need to create a “ghost” glyph entry before we can remap it? Can we create it from scratch (and reference the outline, to get proper copy-paste)? Is there some documentation I am missing?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\directlua{
    fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
        name = "cstm",
        type = "substitution",
        data = {
             [0x261E] = "afii10101",% pointing finger for example
             %[0x261E] = "uni0454",% has NO effect
             ["uni03F5"] = "afii10101",% c-shape, has NO effect
             [0x03F5] = "afii10101",% c-shape, has NO effect
             ["epsilon1"] = "afii10101",% c-shape, has NO effect
             %["uni03B5"] = "afii10101",% 3-shape, has NO effect
             %[0x03B5] = "afii10101",% 3-shape, DOES HAVE effect
             %["epsilon"] = "afii10101",% 3-shape, DOES HAVE effect
} } }
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}[RawFeature=+cstm]
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{EB Garamond Italic}[range=it,RawFeature=+cstm]
\newunicodechar{ϵ}{\char"0454}
\begin{document}
{\addfontfeature{RawFeature=-cstm}\itshape ☞} ← normal\par
{\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+cstm}\itshape ☞} ← substitution in action\par
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
     & 03B5           & 03F5           & 0454           \\
text & ({\itshape ε}) & ({\itshape ϵ}) & ({\itshape є}) \\
math & ($\symit{ε}$)  & ($\symit{ϵ}$)  & {\scshape n/a} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: pdf output]

Comment: I don't think you can do this with font features.  You'll have to create a virtual font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try mapping the glyph at load time of the font.  For some reason it is not italic in math mode but I don't know why.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
local function patch(fontdata)
    if string.match(fontdata.psname or "", "^EBGaramond") then
        fontdata.characters[0x03F5] = fontdata.characters[0x0454]
    end
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("luaotfload.patch_font", patch, "missing glyph")
\end{luacode*}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{EB Garamond}[range=it]
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
     & 03B5           & 03F5           & 0454           \\
text & ({\itshape ε}) & ({\itshape ϵ}) & ({\itshape є}) \\
math & ($\symit{ε}$)  & ($\symit{ϵ}$)  & {\scshape n/a} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You changed `EB Garamond Italic` to `EB Garamond` at line 18. (also, why does `unicode-math` only load single files?) But I think the `ebgaramond` fonts in TeXLive are missing proper italic anyway, at least for this range. Adding back the `Italic` part with [these fonts](https://github.com/octaviopardo/EBGaramond12/tree/master/fonts/otf) I am getting [good results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S66ta.png).

Comment: @svenper For some reason `EB Garamond Italic` could not be found in standard TeXlive 2017.  `unicode-math` is not only loading single files (note that I just patch every font which starts with `EBGaramond`).  The EB Garamond shipped with TeXlive is outdated, so it is to be expected that more recent versions provide better results.

Comment: Is there a way to change the reported unicode value of the generated slot for more semantic search and copy paste, so that `$\epsilon$` becomes `GREEK LUNATE EPSILON SYMBOL` and not `CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER UKRAINIAN IE`?

Comment: @svenper Not that I know of.  I think at this point it might easier to just edit the font file using, e.g., FontForge.

Comment: `\setmathfont{EBGaramond12-Italic}[range=it]` works for an italic glyph in math (other size can probably be set in the optional argument).